# Force \fontdimen 6 for a specific font to silent a microtype warning

Tags: warnings, microtype, fdsymbol

I am using the packages `fdsymbol` together with the `microtype` package and there are many warnings a compile time stating the following:

```
Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolF/m/n/14.4' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.
```

Is there a way to patch the `fdsymbol` package (i.e. to set `\fontdimen 6` to some value) to fix this warning ?

**EDIT**

As asked by egreg, here is an example (which somehow made me discover what was causing the problem... but not solving it).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage[tracking=all]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\ensuremath{\varheartsuit}
\end{document}
```

It seems to be caused by the tracking.

Here is the full warning log for my full document.

```
Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolE/m/n/40' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolE/m/n/27.99988' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolE/m/n/20' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolB/m/n/40' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolB/m/n/27.99988' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolB/m/n/20' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolC/m/n/40' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolC/m/n/27.99988' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolC/m/n/20' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolD/m/n/40' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolD/m/n/27.99988' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolD/m/n/20' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolF/m/n/40' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolF/m/n/27.99988' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.

Package microtype Warning: Font `U/FdSymbolF/m/n/20' does not specify its
(microtype)                \fontdimen 6 (width of an `em')! Therefore,
(microtype)                tracking will not work with this font.
```

Comment: Can you please make a small example that produces the warning?

Comment: just asking: do you really want to add tracking to all fonts?

Comment: @Robert Obviously not... I realized it now. :-/

Comment: Well, I was too optimistic...  `tracking=alltext` did remove some warnings but not all, so the question is still requiring an answer.

Comment: Your code produces no warning with `tracking=alltext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As egreg mentionned it in the comments, setting the microtype package to `tracking=alltext` is enough to remove all the warnings from the basic example.

But, my code is producing a lot more warnings and I did not yet to reproduce it in a small example... In fact, I am using only a few symbols from the fdsymbol package, so I found a workaround as follow :

```latex
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{<->FdSymbolA-Book}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extrasymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheartsuit}{\mathord}{extrasymbols}{184}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medblacksquare}{\mathord}{extrasymbols}{118}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medblackbullet}{\mathord}{extrasymbols}{99}
```

But, it looks like the fdsymbols are used in many more places thant I expected first.

So, I wouldn't say that this answer is the right one. It is just a workaround and I need to discover what is the root of the problem.

Comment: again, are you really sure you want to add tracking to all text fonts? This would be very unusual. Can you say why you want that?

Comment: Not really, but I would like to know how to specify what fonts are taken into consideration and what fonts to exclude. I tried to add `\SetExtraSpacing{font=TS1/FdSymbol*/*/*/*}{}` with no effect...

Comment: see section 4 of the `microtype` manual: Selecting fonts for micro-typography. As @egreg said, with `alltext` the FdSymbol font will not be tracked, so you are doing something else than what you show us (maybe there's math inside a `\textls` command?)

Comment: @Robert Yes, that was exactly the problem! I've got some text inside `\textls{}` and this is what produced these warnings... Thanks a lot, I do not think I would have find it out alone!